# Install Custom Widget on QtCreator

Tags: qt, widget, custom-widgets

I create a custom widget project with a qled. Now, i want to use it on my project but i can't find the correct way to install this custom widget in the qtcreator. Can you help me?

Comment: is that developed as a plugin??

Comment: yes, i developed in a separated project as lib

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-creating-custom-widgets.html#buildingandinstallingtheplugin -- this may help, perhaps